# Get PayPal Client ID from MY CLIENTS email address

Tags: paypal

I am creating a web app where my client will provide an email address where to get paid via PayPal for their customers to pay them. Problem is my clients will mostly have personal accounts and not business.

I know how to create the buttons using the API however I will need my client'ss client-id to render it. For business this is easy and I could give instructions where to find it, but what about personal? Better yet, can it be done programmatically?

> `https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=[HOW DO I GET THIS FROM EMAIL ADDRESS ONLY]&currency=USD&disable-funding=credit,card&locale=en_US`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple alternatives:

1. Instead of using their client-id , use yours and their merchant-id, which they can obtain from their account settings or if you integrate "Log in with PayPal". See https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/configuration/#link-merchantid , the same ID needs to be specified in the v2/checkout/orders `payee.merchant_id` field.
2. Use the `payee.email_address` field: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/pay-another-account/

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! This is the perfect answer. 
I have no idea how I couldn't find that payee variable. SMH. You are a life saver.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to apply this to recurring payments?

Comment: Not this type of subscriptions https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/ , no , they need a business account and API credentials for that